Next available value in Teradata
In Teradata SQL, I'm attempting to write a query that will generate a column that includes the next available value in date sequence order.
So the input is:



CALENDAR_DATE
BUS_DAY_SEQ




2023-11-19



2023-11-20
983


2023-11-21
984


2023-11-22
985


2023-11-23



2023-11-24



2023-11-25



2023-11-26



2023-11-27
986


2023-11-28
987



And the output would be:



CALENDAR_DATE
BUS_DAY_SEQ
NEXT_BUS_DAY_SEQ




2023-11-19

983


2023-11-20
983
983


2023-11-21
984
984


2023-11-22
985
985


2023-11-23

986


2023-11-24

986


2023-11-25

986


2023-11-26

986


2023-11-27
986
986


2023-11-28
987
987



I noticed this post: Next Date Row with Value 1 in Teradata
But I can't seem to get the code in dnoeth's answer to work, and I suspect it's because I'm putting the min() and over() functions in the wrong place in the query.  Please let me know the correct syntax for utilizing these functions to solve the issue.

MIN(BUS_DAY_SEQ)  OVER (ORDER BY CALENDAR_DATE ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT_ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)

Unfortunately, when I try that, I get a syntax error (3706 - "Expecting the word UNBOUNDED").  The actual query I'm running is: "SELECT CALENDAR_DATE, BUS_DAY_SEQ, MIN(BUS_DAY_SEQ) OVER (ORDER BY CALENDAR_DATE ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT_ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM ;"

My typo - should be CURRENT ROW (2 words) not CURRENT_ROW

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
